# RewriteRule with "<" and ">"

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This site I'm working on uses a weird method to pass multiple parameters, the query string looks something like: `?terms=43<|>300,201<|>100`

Server-side, it does `explode('<|>',$_GET['terms'])` to split the parameters (I know, it's too ugly).

This is something I can change but the `<|>` separator must work since links are already spread on other sites. It is actually working on most browsers except IE, IE sends the url as UTF-8 and does not escape the `<` and the `>` (%3C and %3E) like the other browsers does.

On IE, when I enter one of those urls, I only see a 403 error because the `<|>` messes with the rewrite rules from the htaccess and the usual rewrite rules to add the index.php file to the urls is never executed.

So, I need one RewriteRule to change those `<|>` to `|` (with only |, IE works).

I'm trying this, but with no success:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)<\|>(.*)<\|>(.*)$ $1|$2|$3 [NE]
```

(I'm keeping the three parts of the url and replacing the`<|>` with `|`)

Any help?

Comment: When you get a request from IE, what does your Apache show as the URL received?

Comment: on the logs, when the request comes from IE, it shows "terms=123<|>23,233<|>333", when it comes from another browser it shows "terms=123%3C|%3E23,233%3C|%3E333" (all browsers escape < and > while IE sends those characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match the query string in the rule itself, you need to use the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)<\|>(.*)<\|>(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1|%2|%3 [L,R]
```